# Drum trigger controller

Tags: sensor, switches, controller, trigger

I'm planning to make a drum controller (something like arduino) for pc using a piezo transducer as sensor, some electronic circuit, keyboard PCB connected to usb and sampler for drums in pc. I found out that some people have similar plan, but they didn't finish it.
So my plan may look like: I hit the piezo, signal will be amplified with OP amp, then I need something what basically connect two contact in keyboard (e.g. for letter "A") or just lower resistance between them under 40k with with the piezo signal. I used transistor as switch. Hope that you understand it. I designed scheme below, but it doesn´t working. Please help.

[image: diagram]

[image]

Keyboard PCB

Comment: You should take a look at the Arduino Leonardo.  It's all you need.  It will deal with the Piezo inputs as well as the USB keyboard emulation.

Comment: This is quite a typical high hopes -project. It starts from the middle. Something which works should be based on what kind of signal is available from the piezo sensor. If one sticks a low cost piezo on an acoustic drumhead or a cymbal he gets an incredible complex  slowly decaying noisy pulse, impossible to decide  when the drum or cymbal actually is hit, full also ghost hits of neighbour drums.  Clever signal processing software can calculate it afterwards but that's useless during the actual playing. In addition processing delay as short as 15ms makes the timing inferior in live playing.

Comment: (Continued) Drumpads in electronic drumkits are quiet. Hits do not initiate vibrations, drumpads output clean easy to detect short pulses. Pulses do not have long noisy tails which could easily hide weaker hits. With properly designed pads this project has some possibilities. But it removes all hit strength variations and the questioner obviously knows nothing of the actual electrical signals of the keyboard scanner nor how much delay and (worse) timing variation it will cause. Constant delay could be compensated in recordings, but varying timing jitter (say plusminus 10ms) is intolerable.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you haven't accounted for the saturation voltage of the transistor you are using as a switch.  This is usually around 200 mV for a BJT.  These types of transistor aren't good for switching very low voltages, like your 40 mV.  To do that, use a FET instead.

However, are you really sure that your keyboard is looking for a switch closure, using only 40 mV to sense it?  That voltage sounds low.  I suspect the real problem is the keyboard doesn't work the way you think it does.  Buttons may not be just mechanical switches.  Some keyboards work on capacitive sensing, others magnetic, for example.

Comment: I will try replace transistor, but I don´t know much about FET transistor. **Would you advice me what kind of FET transistor I should buy in my case?** That voltage I measured on two diffrent keyboards so I think that´s right. Keyboard what I have works on mechanical switches and I think that normal pc keyboard also works so. [Keyboard working](http://www.explainthatstuff.com/computerkeyboards.html)     I wanted to ask one more question. **That op-amp must have symetric power supply or just single supply, that minus on op amp connected do groung?**

Comment: @Bonc: If you measured the voltage with just a meter, then it may not be valid.  The controller is probably scanning the keys, so the actual voltage when reading the key is higher, but it happens such a small fraction of the overall time that it averages to 40 mV.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar project. Using a piezo on a drum, so that when you hit the drum an arduino can detect the piezo signal.
I have a couple questions: 
Is your amplifier circuit built exactly like that? Because that amplifier will not do anything without feedback. Look up a non-inverter op-amp circuit. 
You will probably want a microcontroller to do the switching. Because a Piezo, when hit, will cycle through positive and negative voltages. So the transistor will switch on and off a lot. You might be able to get around this by using an envelope detector. It is built with a capacitor and a diode allowing all positive voltages and a slow (exponential) decay.

Hope that helps. Let me know if you have questions.

Josh

Comment: My circuit is not built exactly like arduino, but I think that working similar. I don´t put there feedback on op-amp because I think it would cause decrase gain coefficient on op amp - maybe there is the mistake. That evelope detector is a good idea, but first a just want to circuit work.

Comment: The gain of an op amp is ideally infinity. But this is obviously not possible, so the op amp will always be the voltage of +Vcc (the supply voltage). It would be a good idea to do a quick google search on non-inverting op amp circuits. They are very simple to build and calculate the gain.

Comment: The whole purpose of adding feedback is so that you can control the gain.

Comment: I found this circuit for amplifying the signal and it looks pretty sensitivy - for drums would be great. Do you think that I can connect base/gate of transistor just to output of op amp? - where is a led on circuit.  [circuit](http://s243.photobucket.com/user/kinglord1608/media/vibration_zpsc75d22f1.png.html) [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T821y0NYac4)